Concept of signal size for energy saving in optimization
I've been trying to redo this optimization problem from this paper, but on GEKKO Python code instead of MatLAB as they did, which is about finding the maximum Biodiesel concentration at final time:
J = max $x_4(t_f)$
s.t.
enter image description here
where $k_i=A_iexp(\frac{-b_i}{T})$ and A, b are tabulated values
and $298 < T < 338$ (Kelvin)
I was able to find the same x4(tf), as well as the temperature profile through Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization, which is the polynomial:
$$T(t)=335.05 + 28.545\cdot(t-50)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{500}-11.659\cdot(t^2-100t+\frac{5000}{3})\cdot\frac{3\sqrt{500e^6}}{500e^6}$$
However, the authors proceed by evaluating the maximum Biodiesel concentration with energy contemplation:
"Unlike the previous Optimal Control Problem statement,the optimization criterion, in this case, take into account the size of the control action as an indirect measure of signal energy. For this, an indirect measure is considered that is strictly related to the energy consumption for the control action. This measure is the 'signal size'. In signal processing, the 'size' of a signal would involve some notion of its strength (Nearing, 2017). The squared size Es of a continuous-time signal x(t) is quantified by the mathematical concept of the norm. There are several conceptions of the signal size that can
be defined for signals. In the next section, the norm will be
mathematically defined:
$E_s=\Vert T_R\Vert^2 = \langle T_R, T_R \rangle$
Therefore, the objective is to find the best temperature profile with a minimum control signal size to achieve the maximum concentration of biodiesel at the end of the reaction. Then, the performance index is:
$J^* = max [(1-R)x_4(t_f) - R \Vert T(t)-T_{amb} \Vert^2]$"
Where R is the weighting of the second term and $T_{amb}$ is constant 298 K.
Nonetheless, I can't understand this concept of "signal size" and the squared norm of the range of temperature. I believe it's a huge number, so wouldn't it explode the optimization function J*? According to the authors' results:
enter image description here
The signal size is on the order of $e^5$, so I would think that if I input that into the dynamic modelling, it would explode the concentration values and the temperature profile. But the authors found the following profiles:
enter image description here
enter image description here
What am I missing here on the "signal size"? I've been trying to look up for this subject in various sites, but I'm heading to nowhere.
Thank you in advance!
Paper: doi.org/10.1016/j.cherd.2021.11.001
